# Django json, Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json:

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

I've been trying to create a register form for django 1.10 and it almost works fine except that when I make the post works fine, but redirects to the url of the ajax post and in Chrome inspector I see something like this: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "http://127.0.0.1:8500/reg/".

And then displays my json response: {"reg": "ok", "email": "logdo@fujasldm.com"}

Because of that undesired redirection I can't handle the response on the page that I have my form.

This is my ajax:

```
$('#botonregistro').on('submit', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 console.log("reg!") // sanity check

 $.ajax({
  url: "/reg/", // the endpoint
  type: "POST", // http method
  data: {
   username: $('#id_username').val(),
   password: $('#id_password').val(),
   email: $('#id_email').val(),
   sexo: $('#id_sexo').val(),
   interes: $('#id_interes').val()

  }, // data sent with the post request

  success: function(response) {
   $('.home-reg-form').empty();
   console.log(json);
   console.log("success");
  },

  error: function(response) {
   $('.home-reg-form').empty();
   $('.home-reg-form').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
  }
 });

});
```

And this is my view from the post url:

```
def reg_ajax(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uname = request.POST.get('username')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        psw = request.POST.get('password')

        user = User.objects.create_user(username=uname, email=email, password=psw)

        response = JsonResponse({'reg':'ok', 'email': email})
        return response

    else:
        response = JsonResponse({'reg':'error'})
        return response
```

I believe that the code is fine, but maybe I missed something.

Comment: Try passing `dataType: 'json'` to `$.ajax()`. Does it help?

Comment: Thanks for answering, already tried that but without success :(

Comment: As a quick fix, try changing the mimetype of the response to plain text.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I failed to post my html form code, there was an error related to that, specifically in this part:

```
$('#botonregistro').on('submit', function(e)
```

My selector is wrong, that id is from my submit button instead of my form id.

Thanks for all your answers, I still have to learn from that rookie mistakes.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, can you expand on the problem you had?

Comment: Just check that you are using the correct selector, the problem was that my form have on id selector like '#form' and also my submit button have a id selector like '#submitbutton', I was using $('#submitbutton').on('submit', function(e) instead of $('#form').on('submit', function(e)